# Pre-fill input text box

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know of a good small piece of code that will prefill my user and pass input box with the text username and password. I've seen so jscript that will do it but i'm looking for something that is a few lines a code.

similar to how the search text is in the search box up top on the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<input type="text" style="color:#ccc;" value="username" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='username' ? '' : this.value; this.style.color='#000';" onfocusout="this.value = this.value == '' ? this.value = 'username' : this.value; this.value=='username' ? this.style.color='#ccc' : this.style.color='#000'"/>

<input type="text" style="color:#ccc;" value="password" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='password' ? '' : this.value; this.style.color='#000';" onfocusout="this.value = this.value == '' ? this.value = 'password' : this.value; this.value=='password' ? this.style.color='#ccc' : this.style.color='#000'"/>
```

Comment: ...and this is standard HTML. BTW, feel free to externalize the strings 'username' and 'password' to constants, and/or any other necessary refactoring.

Answer (score 18):

For browsers that support HTML5, adding placeholder="search" will add the prefill text automatically.

The search text box at the top of the page has:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" >
```

You can use an HTML5 shim to make this backwards compatible. Example:
http://kamikazemusic.com/web-development/revisiting-html5-placeholder-fixes/

Comment: Good one! And @acctman, in case you didn't know, that can be figured out by viewing the source of this page, using the "View Page Source" option (right-click anywhere on this page).

Comment: Here a more up-to-date link to the placeholder shim: http://kamikazemusic.com/web-development/revisiting-html5-placeholder-fixes/

Works great! Thanks